# Getting all root properties

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Let's say I have a DocumentDB collection populated with documents that have this shape:

```
[{ "Name": "KT",    "Dob": "5/25/1990", "Children": [], "IsMale": false },
 { "Name": "Chris", "Dob": "10/1/1980", "Children": [], "IsMale": true }]
```

Now let's say I don't the structure of the documents above.

Is there a query I can write that will return me a distinct list of those property names (`"Name"`, `"Dob"`, `"Children"`, `"IsMale"`)?

In other words, is there a way for be to sniff out the schema of those documents?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406528/in-azure-documentdb-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-properties-in-a-collection/34406862#34406862). In any case, the answers there might give you some ideas.

tl;dr; The only way to do it is to read all of the docs. You can pull them all back to your machine or you can read them inside of a stored procedure and only send the calculated schema back to your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dynamic [ORM or ODM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) for Azure DocumentDB like [Slazure](http://www.slazure.com/) to do something like this. Example follows:

```
using SysSurge.Slazure.AzureDocumentDB.Linq;
using SysSurge.Slazure.Core;
using SysSurge.Slazure.Core.Linq.QueryParser;

public void EnumProperties()
{
    // Get a reference to the collection
    dynamic storage = new QueryableStorage<DynDocument>("URL=https://contoso.documents.azure.com:443/;DBID=DDBExample;TOKEN=VZ+qKPAkl9TtX==");
    QueryableCollection<DynDocument> collection = storage.TestCustomers;

    // Build collection query
    var queryResult = collection.Where("SignedUpForNewsletter = true and Age < 22");

    foreach (DynDocument document in queryResult)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IDynProperty> keyValuePair in document)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Key);
        }
    }
}
```