# how can get the columns information from cosmos db collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using spark connector for cosmos db, but I want to get only column information from the collection as below given example.

Collection:

```
 [
 {
 "AMT_INCOME_TOTAL": 135000,
 "NAME_FAMILY_STATUS": null,
 "FLAG_OWN_REALTY": null,
 "NAME_HOUSING_TYPE": null,
 "DAYS_BIRTH": -18981,
 "NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE": null,
 "CNT_CHILDREN": 0,
 "NAME_CONTRACT_TYPE": null,
 "FLAG_CONT_MOBILE": 1,
 "FLAG_WORK_PHONE": 0,
 "SK_ID_CURR": 421505,
 "FLAG_MOBIL": 1,
 "id": "5b422022-4fd9-41b6-9634-46fb9066c600",
 "AMT_GOODS_PRICE": 697500,
 "NAME_INCOME_TYPE": null,
 "ORGANIZATION_TYPE": null,
 "FLAG_OWN_CAR": null,
 "FLAG_PHONE": 0,
 "AMT_ANNUITY": 33777,
 "CNT_FAM_MEMBERS": null,
 "OWN_CAR_AGE": null,
 "AMT_CREDIT": 794173.5,
 "OCCUPATION_TYPE": null,
 "DAYS_REGISTRATION": -10906,
 "DAYS_ID_PUBLISH": -2522,
 "DAYS_EMPLOYED": -989,
 "FLAG_EMP_PHONE": 1,
 "CODE_GENDER": null,
 "NAME_TYPE_SUITE": null,
 "_rid": "oQg3AJL4IrkBAAAAAAAAAA==",
 "_self": "dbs/oQg3AA==/colls/oQg3AJL4Irk=/docs/oQg3AJL4IrkBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
 "_etag": "\"6f01a675-0000-1900-0000-5f8409f30000\"",
 "_attachments": "attachments/",
 "_ts": 1602488819
 },
 {
 "EMPLOYEE_ID": 101,
 "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Dom",
 "id": "b44dc898-cb85-4db6-9f3d-8dda1f57fdca",
 "EMPLOYEE_ADD": "Florida",
 "FILE_NAME": "XLSX_Files/Employee_Data.xlsx",
 "EMPLOYEE_CONTACTNO": 9851,
 "_rid": "oQg3AJL4IrmldgQAAAAAAA==",
 "_self": "dbs/oQg3AA==/colls/oQg3AJL4Irk=/docs/oQg3AJL4IrmldgQAAAAAAA==/",
 "_etag": "\"00000481-0000-1900-0000-5fbcef090000\"",
 "_attachments": "attachments/",
 "_ts": 1606217481
 }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
 AMT_INCOME_TOTAL
 NAME_FAMILY_STATUS
 FLAG_OWN_REALTY 
 NAME_HOUSING_TYPE 
 DAYS_BIRTH
 NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE 
 CNT_CHILDREN
 NAME_CONTRACT_TYPE 
 FLAG_CONT_MOBILE
 FLAG_WORK_PHONE
 SK_ID_CURR
 FLAG_MOBIL
 id 
 AMT_GOODS_PRICE
 NAME_INCOME_TYPE 
 ORGANIZATION_TYPE 
 FLAG_OWN_CAR 
 FLAG_PHONE
 AMT_ANNUITY
 CNT_FAM_MEMBERS 
 OWN_CAR_AGE 
 AMT_CREDIT
 OCCUPATION_TYPE 
 DAYS_REGISTRATION
 DAYS_ID_PUBLISH
 DAYS_EMPLOYED
 FLAG_EMP_PHONE
 CODE_GENDER 
 NAME_TYPE_SUITE 
 EMPLOYEE_ID
 EMPLOYEE_NAME
 EMPLOYEE_ADD
 FILE_NAME
 EMPLOYEE_CONTACTNO
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Azure DocumentDB, how can I get a list of all properties in a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406528/in-azure-documentdb-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-properties-in-a-collection)

Comment: No, do we have any other way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**No, there is no simple way to do that.**

### Why?

CosmosDB is schemaless and designed for unlimited horizontal scale. Every document on every partition could contain any content and to my knowledge there is no API to query any metabase about document tree. The documents don't even have to be indexed on every node, so what you are asking is not something that would fit the picture of schemaless endless-scale storage.

### What you can do?

You can achieve this but it would add complexity and would require some tinkering.

#### Read all the documents

Want to know aggregate of all documents in runtime, you have to read all the documents and reduce the result to unique tree structure. That will not scale and most likely that is too absurd to even try.

#### Create index document yourself via triggers

Since CosmosDB does not provide suitable indexed data for you, you could manage this index yourself. Basically, you could set up one special document (i.e. `partitionKey=null, id="myMagicColumnMap"`), and on each create/update/delete upgrade this document with used property names.

You can read about [How to write CosmosDB triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#triggers).

Do note that this means quite some work for every CosmosDB write operation and there are cost, concurrency, error handling and other such issues to consider.

#### Create index document outside of CosmosDB

It may be better to implement updating the index document outside of your CosmosDB collection (even if you store it in CosmosDB). This way you can still utilize the full cosmosDB speed and you can isolate the impact of your custom indexing better.

Simplest way would be to let you client app pass your requests through some layer and if any new columns are found then persist them to your index.

Or you could also leverage [CosmosDB Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) as separate client to find the added columns by processing added/changed document batches. This way your indexing is also independent of clients actually working on the data. (Though, if i remember correctly, change feed currently did not pick up delete operations, you'd have to manage those separately).