# How to query all Union of all JSON Properties(Schema) in Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have need to create Relational Table that will map its column to all the properties of JSON data for Product.
Since Azure Cosmos DB can store arbitrary JSON Data, how can i get the schema that will include union all properties from all rows ?

I am only interested in getting schema of all the properties.
when i query cosmos DB
i get the following output

```
{
  "id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "ProductId" : "ABCXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "Name":"Product Name",
  "IsDeleted":"Yes",
  "CountryName" : {
   "Id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "Name":"CountryName"
  },
  "DateCreated":"10-Aug-2010"
}
```

Now this Schema could have modified and more fields could have been added to it.

say after six month one more field was added "ModifiedDate" and new schema looks like the following

```
{
  "id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "ProductId" : "ABCXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "Name":"Product Name",
  "IsDeleted":"Yes",
  "CountryName" : {
   "Id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "Name":"CountryName"
  },
  "DateCreated":"10-Aug-2010",
  "ModifiedDate":"10-Jan-2011
}
```

So on over the period of time more field might have been added.

if i query products of 2010, i don't get to see the new fields that were added say in 2011 or later.

My question is wan to get full schema(with all the fields/properties) and just the schema only till today.

How do i get that in cosmos DB?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, as there are no "relational tables" or columns in Cosmos DB. What schema are you referring to? Please edit to provide more details. Also, please show your work (relevant code, data, etc). Right now, what you've provided is a high level description of your requirement with no specifics.

Comment: FYI there is no way to retrieve a distinct list of all properties, aside from reading every document in the collection and creating the list for yourself. Or... keep track of them somewhere in your app. Also, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406528/in-azure-documentdb-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-properties-in-a-collection), from several years ago. Just note that, in the accepted answer, it suggests using a stored procedure, but stored procs are partition-scoped and would require an invocation per partition key value.