# Get distinct list of fields for all container items

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I understand that

a) Cosmos db, as a NoSQL db, does not have a schema
b) That items in a container can differ in the "shape" of that data from item to item.

Is it possible to get a visual of the fullest "shape" of an item if all of the permutations of fields for items in that container were expressed?

**Example:** A Container called Employee with 3 items

```json
{
"userId":"rirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Romin",
"lastName":"Irani"
}

{
"userId":"nirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Neil",
"lastName":"Irani",
"preferredFullName":"Neil Irani"
}

{
"userId":"thanks",
"jobTitleName":"Program Directory",
"firstName":"Tom",
"lastName":"Hanks",
"employeeCode":"E3"
}
```

A view of all of the fullest shape for that item, ie all field permutations would be

```json
{
"userId":"",
"jobTitleName":"",
"firstName":"",
"lastName":"",
"preferredFullName":"",
"employeeCode":""
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Azure DocumentDB, how can I get a list of all properties in a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406528/in-azure-documentdb-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-properties-in-a-collection)

Comment: Please see linked question, which already has an answer explaining this. Tl;dr you can't do what you're doing, without doing some type of custom processing of your own, involving ingesting the entire collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Possible unless you retrieve all items and do an iteration to get the fields, you need to know that Azure CosmosDB NOSQL API is a schema-agnostic. Schema inference is not something available out of the box.

Comment: How can I query it fully if I don't know the available fields?

Comment: If you are using SDK you can retrive all items through pagination and do a sampling. Check the documentation based on the SDK